# Laravel 5 Class Log Could not be Found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am elbows deep in Laravel 5 and it's proving to be quite the bugger with the lack of autoloading. I am running into the weirdest of errors. I can't Log anything on my localhost. If it's a PHP error, it logs just fine, but if I try to write to the log, it throws an error. It's a Windows so no File Permission errors. Here's the error I get:

```
[2015-02-11 20:09:40] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Log' not found' in C:\xampp\htdocs\bg_checks\laravel\app\Http\Controllers\BgInfoController.php:44
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\bg_checks\laravel\storage\framework\compiled.php(1721): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->fatalExceptionFromError(Array)
#1 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleShutdown()
```

Laravel 5 is still pretty new so there's not a lot of info on it. I've tried to find something and can only find a forum on Laracast's forum and nothing they suggested worked.

Help!

Comment: You need to use the "FQN" of the Log class. It thinks you are referring to a Log class in your controllers namespace.

Comment: @Scopey, thanks for the info! I managed to get it to write using `\Log::info('test');`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I don't think you have a `Log` class file in `App\Http\Controllers` directory. So you must add

```
use Log;
```

if you are using Laravel's logger, or

```
use Path\To\Your\Log;
```

for a custom logger.

Comment: This worked. Bah! I tried every other use and couldn't get it. Also:

`\Log::info('test');`

works as well. Same with Validation. So annoying. Thanks Martiros!

Comment: This begs the question, how do you just "know" which classes to include? How can i figure that out proactively?

Comment: Log class is part of laravel framework
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/errors#logging

that why I wrote -> "use Log;
if you are using laravel logger "

Comment: in response to my own comment above, you can simply look for the class file - /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/. also just doing a find all throughout your project in phpstorm et al, for the class name your using say find all = "class Seeder" then just put together the classes namespace ie Illuminate\Database + class name ie Seeder