# laravel Log not found in application.php

Tags: laravel-5

I want to use `Log`to log ,it works in controller,but it doesn't work in application(vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php)

this is my code:

```
    <?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation;

use Log;
use Closure;
use RuntimeException;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Container\Container;
use Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Events\EventServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Routing\RoutingServiceProvider;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request as SymfonyRequest;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application as ApplicationContract;
class Application extends Container implements ApplicationContract, HttpKernelInterface
{

public function make($abstract, array $parameters = [])
{
    $abstract = $this->getAlias($abstract);

    if (isset($this->deferredServices[$abstract])) {
        $this->loadDeferredProvider($abstract);
    }

    Log::info('test info '); // 698 line
    return parent::make($abstract, $parameters);
}
```

I catch the error when I up the artisan serve:

php artisan serve

```
Fatal error: Class 'Log' not found in      vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application. php on line 698
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 Class Log Could not be Found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28463823/laravel-5-class-log-could-not-be-found?rq=1). Try using `\Log` instead

Comment: It is not work still when i use `\Log::info('test info '); `.

Comment: Log facade will probably load after this file. So you can't use it here. Also if it's not for test pusposes do not change source files. use override concept to modify functions.